# .NET SQLite provider can't find my table anymore

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Early I used to run :

```
using (SQLiteConnection sqlite_connection =
    new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="
        + armc.Model.Settings.dbpath
        + ";Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;")) {
    sqlite_connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_command = sqlite_connection.CreateCommand();
    sqlite_command.CommandText = "select * from `archive`"; // ???
    SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader = sqlite_command.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlite_datareader.Read()) {
        m_products.Add
            (new Product("val", int.Parse(sqlite_datareader["value"].ToString())));
        }
    }
```

But now I'm getting:

$exception  {"SQLite error\r\nno such table: archive"}  System.Exception {System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException}

I don't understand what has changed but I still can work with that sqlite using C++ api and using SQLite 2009 Pro util but something is going wrong with .NET provider for .NET 4.0.

Had tried to change database, save as RSA and seems like nothing happens so far, what esle could be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="
        + armc.Model.Settings.dbpath
        + ";Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;"))
```

set Property `New` to `False`

Comment: sadly same with that, I even had tried to set compress as false

Comment: delete db file, create db with `new=true`, set `new=false`, create table